Why is this css sibling selector not selecting all the siblings?


  li:has(>label) {
    background: #0c0;
  }
  li~li:has(>label) {
    border: 4px solid #c0c;
  }
  
  
<ul tabindex="-1">
<li><input type="radio"/ name="r6a" id="r61a" value="6.0a" /><label for="r60a">[Item 6.0]</label></li>
<li tabindex="0">[Item 6.1]</li>
<li><input type="radio"/ name="r6a" id="r62a" value="6.2a" /><label for="r62a">[Item 6.2]</label></li>
<li><input type="radio"/ name="r6a" id="r63a" value="6.3a" /><label for="r63a">[Item 6.3]</label></li>
<li tabindex="0">[Item 6.4]</li>
</ul>



As I read this, the first selector is selecting lis that have a label as direct descender and the second is selecting all lis that are siblings to a li that has a label. But why is the last selector just selecting items 6.2 and 6.3? It should either select all of them (inclusively all are siblings to a li that has a label) or it should select 6.1 and 6.4 (if it is exclusive).
According to this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator
They dont have to be next to each other, just share the same parent. Which they do.

The second setting is selecting all lis that are siblings (come after, not before, so that's all except the first one in this example) an li and that have a label as a direct descendant, not the other way round as you have interpreted it.

Then how do I select all lis that have the same parent as a li that has a label as direct descentant?

Does your requirement boil down to: select all lis in a list when any single one of them (or more) has a label as a direct descendant? In your example that will be all the lis in that ul because the ul has a child with a direct descendant that is a label.

"According to this: [...] They dont have to be next to each other, just share the same parent." - you ignored one important part there: "The subsequent-sibling combinator (~, a tilde) separates two selectors and matches all instances of the second element that follow the first element (not necessarily immediately) and share the same parent element."

The requirement is to :

select all lis that have the same parent as a li that has a label as
direct descentant

So you want all the lis in a ul to be selected if any one of them has a label as a direct descendant.
You can use :has on the ul (ie the parent) for this:


  ul:has(>li>label) > li { 
    border: 4px solid #c0c;
  }
  
  
<ul tabindex="-1">
<li><input type="radio"/ name="r6a" id="r61a" value="6.0a" /><label for="r60a">[Item 6.0]</label></li>
<li tabindex="0">[Item 6.1]</li>
<li><input type="radio"/ name="r6a" id="r62a" value="6.2a" /><label for="r62a">[Item 6.2]</label></li>
<li><input type="radio"/ name="r6a" id="r63a" value="6.3a" /><label for="r63a">[Item 6.3]</label></li>
<li tabindex="0">[Item 6.4]</li>
</ul>



